# Replicating and adding view and contents in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to take a UIView and its contents (labels, textfields, and buttons) and replicate and add its master view after runtime?

I created a form in my app and a user can add places they have visited. As an app would not know how many places a user has gone beforehand, I would like to have the UIView holding the places info to have a plus button so that when pressed, it will replicate those fields to allow a user to enter their next place (like you would on a web form).

If you know of a resource, please let me know as well! It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is this different than what a UITableView does?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up converting the form field into a UIViewTable.

Each cell has a add button and remove button and they are hooked up with the adding and removing functions with:

```
    cell?.removeButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell?.removeButton.addTarget(self, action: "removeEntry:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    cell?.addButton.addTarget(self, action: "addEntry:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Each function looks like so:

```
func removeEntry(sender: UIButton!) {

    println("removed entry field")

    self.places.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)
    self.addresses.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)
    self.reviews.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)

    tableView.reloadData()
}

func addEntry(sender: UIButton!) {

    println("added entry field")

    self.places.append("")
    self.addresses.append("")
    self.reviews.append("")

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```